# scanf data in hex format into unsigned shorts

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I would like to `fscanf` from a stream containing data like `ABCD0000` into `unsigned short` variables.

What is the proper format specifier for that? I was unable to find any way of combining both "unsigned" and "hexadecimal" with the `h` (short) specifier.

Take for instance

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short hex_input;
char byte;

int main(void) {
    scanf("%hX", &hex_input);
    printf("%hX\n", hex_input);
    byte = hex_input >> 8;
    printf("%hu\n", byte);
    byte = (char)hex_input;
    printf("%hu\n", byte);
    return 0;
}
```

And the data `AB00`. What I get as output is:

```
AB00
65451
0
```

Note that the second line is wrong, I would expect `171` (the `AB` part).

Comment: @JeffG: I rolled back this edit as it made the question inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `hx` still. (Hexadecimal is handled as unsigned by default.) Also note that your example of `ABCD0000` will only have its lower four nybbles read into an unsigned short, so you'll end up getting a value of `0`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Please have a look at the revised question.

Comment: You're printing a 16-bit %hu for a byte sized value. Note that 65451 is FFAB in hex. That tells me you're on a little endian architecture and that you're getting a junk FF in the byte with a higher order of magnitude... or it's casting it automatically to a wider type.

Comment: Oh, I was missing the `unsigned` for `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion specifier `%hx` (or `%hX` equivalently) expects a pointer to an `unsigned short`, there is no *signed* version of hexadecimal conversion, but a leading `-` sign in the input stream will be recognised and handled using unsigned arithmetic.

The reason you get `65451` for the first `byte` is type `char` is signed on your system, so `0xAB` is converted to `-85` when stored to `byte`. `byte` is passed to `printf` as an `int`, with the same value `-85` and `printf` converts it to an `unsigned short` for the format specifier `%hu`, producing `0xFFAB` or `65451`.

To avoid such problems, always use `unsigned char` when dealing with byte values.

To convert `ABCD0000` as 2 unsigned shorts, you can specify a length of 4, limiting the number of bytes consumed to 4:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned short s1, s2;
    unsigned char byte;

    int n = scanf("%4hx%4hx", &s1, &s2);
    if (n >= 1) {
        printf("s1: %hX - %u, %u\n", s1, s1 >> 8, (unsigned char)s1);
    }
    if (n >= 2) {
        printf("s2: %hX - %u, %u\n", s2, s2 >> 8, (unsigned char)s2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```